# Win32 application wired memory usage

Tags: windows, flutter, memory, memory-leaks, virtualalloc

I have write an win32 application using flutter 3.0.5. It uses some third party library and shared library also written by me.
Currently I found there is wired memory usage.

Once the application start up, it would take around 150MB memory. If I do nothing, just leave it there. The memory occupied would not grow up. But if I open chrome with multiple times or launch some games. The memory occupied by this application would grow up to around 600-800MB. The more tabs in chrome, the more memory it would occupied.
Even if I pause this application using INT 3. The memory still grow up.
Using tool VMMap, I found some clue.
[image: Before memory grow up]
[image: After memory grow up]
This phenomenon only happened on specified machine.
I have no idea why this happened. Could anyone help me about this?